# square textures for circular particles in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having trouble rendering particles properly in three.js. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/) to set up particles. Unfortunately, while they're placed correctly and are displayed, they are clearly rectangular, rather than circular. 
[image]
Here's the code for the material

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(   
"textures/disc.png",
function(texture) {

  var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    size: 16,
    map: texture,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  });

  particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
});
```

and [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jAGRkk)'s a pen with complete code.

I honestly have no idea why they're rendered like that, when it's working perfectly in the example in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the fog is being added to your particles. Set `fog` to `false` in the `PointMaterial`

```js
var scene,
        camera, fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane, HEIGHT, WIDTH,
        renderer, container;

function createScene() {
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xf7d9aa, 100, 950)
  aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  fieldOfView = 60;
  nearPlane = 1;
  farPlane = 10000;
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    fieldOfView,
    aspectRatio,
    nearPlane,
    farPlane
  );

  camera.position.x = 10;
  camera.position.z = 290;
  camera.position.y = 25;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });

    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0, 0, 0));
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  container = document.getElementById('world');
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);
}

function handleWindowResize() {
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}


var hemisphereLight, shadowLight;

function createLights() {
}

var sphere;
function createSphere() {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 150, 32, 32 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    sphere.visible = false;
    scene.add( sphere );
}

function createParticles() {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = loader.load(      
        "https://i.imgur.com/9fW07EI.png",
      function(texture) {
        editGeometry = sphere.geometry;
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        for ( i = 0; i < editGeometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {

          geometry.vertices.push(editGeometry.vertices[i]);

        }

        var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
          color: 0xFFFFFF,
          size: 16,
          map: texture,
          transparent: true,
          blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
          fog: false,
          depthTest: false,
        });

        particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
        particles.sortParticles = true;
        scene.add( particles );
    });
}

function loop() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}


function init() {
    createScene();
    createLights();
    createSphere();
    createParticles();
    loop();
}
init()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="world">
</div>
```

Note that if your image is not on the same domain as your webpage then you can't use the image in WebGL unless you both request cross origin access **and** the server serving the image gives permission.

Also you can't use images from a 3rd party domain unless the server sends CORS headers for permission to use the image. The `postimg.org` server did not give permission for the image. imgur's server did.

You must also turn off the `depthTest` otherwise points drawn in front will end up blocking out points drawn in back. Since you're drawing with transparency and additive blending that's probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly it!

Comment: could you rewrite this answer in a way that it clarifies that turning off depthTest is (part of) the solution? Right now it basically says it is just a setting unrelated to the problem/question, but its not!

Answer (score 1):

It's not work for me, maybe I use a **ShaderMaterial**, but `depthTest: false` works.

```
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                uniforms: {
                    uColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
                    uPointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(require('./res/spark1')) }
                },
                vertexShader: _me.vertex_shader,
                fragmentShader: _me.fragment_shader,

                depthTest: false,
                transparent: true,
                // fog: false
            })
```